# Heroku Toggle between sso and standard email login

Tags: authentication, heroku

I work for a web development company that uses SSO for one client and standard email login for another.

After logging in with SSO I am now automatically routed to SSO login each time I go to Heroku.

How do I toggle back to standard login?

Comment: I'd try clearing cookies for heroku.com or using an incognito window.

Comment: I have been using the incognito and that works but having another window open without any of my other tabs is just a pain. Will try the cookies but still seems like another unnecessary step

Comment: Well, they're clearly setting a cookie that says "this user uses SSO, give them that flow", so you're going to have to find a way to deal with that. If you use Firefox, [containers may be helpful too](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/).